# number of ways of arranging the letters of the word ARRANGE in which two R's are always together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can the letters of the word ARRANGE be arranged such that two R's are never together?

Now total number of words are $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$.

Now words in which R's are always together are $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$. Subtracting these two doesn't give me correct answer. Can you explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: There are $15$ possible positions for the two R such that they are not together (place one and count positions for the other, always on the right to avoid duplicates, or if you prefer there are ${7 \choose 2}=21$ pairs and $6$ for which the R are together). Hence the total number of words is for this case $15\times5!/2=15\times60=900$. You can check that $7!/(2!2!)=1260$ and as Uddeshya Singh wrote below, there are $6!/2!=360$ words such that the two R are together, and you get the sum right: $360+900=1260$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second case. It will be just $\frac{6!}{2!}$.  Because your are taking 'RR' as a single unit which can be adjusted only one way

Comment: huh ? let me for time being take as R' and R''. won't i get two copied if i don't divide by 2. as an example consider ANGER'R''A and ANGER''R'A.

Comment: Won't they both mean the same thing? @J.Deff . We are talking about permutating two IDENTICAL OBJECTS together. it just makes it $\frac{2!}{2!}$ =1!?

Comment: they are same word, but two copies

Comment: Tell me why would you like to count EGG and EGG as two different words when even the dictionary says they are the same. Basically in this case, we have 6 things to align. "A"x2 , "RR","N","G","E". Thus it makes it $\frac{6!}{2!}*\frac{2!}{2!}$. @J.Deff

Comment: then why we have divided by 2, in case of A's

Comment: @J.Deff, Same logic. $AA^{'}$ and $A^{'}A$ will mean the same thing. I suggest you to read about basic permutations. It's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56905/discussion-between-uddeshya-singh-and-j-deff).

Comment: no thanks for help